# Commutation $[H_0, \phi_0(\vec{x},t)]$ in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian, commutator, time-evolution

Studying from Schwartz "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" p. 23, I got to the part where he discusses time dependence of the field operator $\phi$ and the annihilation/creation operators $a_p, a_p^\dagger$ in the Heisenberg picture. He commutes the Free Hamiltonian $H_0$ with the free fields $\phi_0(\vec{x}, t)$ and finds that
$$\begin{align}[H_0, \phi_0(\vec{x}, t)] &=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\left[\omega_p\left(a_p^\dagger a_p+\frac{1}{2}\right), a_ke^{-ikx}+a_k^\dagger e^{ikx}\right] \\&= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(-\omega_pa_pe^{-ipx}+\omega_pa_p^\dagger e^{ipx}) \\&= -i\partial_t{\phi_0(\vec{x}, t)}. \end{align}\tag{2.79}$$

I get how he goes from the second line to the third, but how does he jump from the first to the second? I tried to yield the commutation relations myself but I don't know how he contracts one integral into the other.

Answer (score 1):

When performing the commutator, note that $[a(k), a^{\dagger}(p)]$ is proportional to $\delta(k-p)$. By integrating the delta function over $k$, it will get rid of the integral over k, which is how he “contracts” the integral as you call it. Does that make sense?